# Error 516 Renaming file in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Moved failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 516.)

```
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

    var getImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Image.png")
    var toImagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Image-"+sWordId+".png")

    //let image = UIImage(named: getImagePath)
    //i1.image = image

    var error: NSError?
    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if filemgr.moveItemAtPath(getImagePath, toPath: toImagePath, error: &error) {
        println("Move successful")
    } else {
        println("Moved failed with error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that there is already a file with the same name at the destination path.